# Pre Populate jquery token input textbox with php mysql result

Tags: jquery, input, textbox, token

I'm using [this](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)
jQuery token input to the user choose languages and submit it to his MySql database. (Like facebook settings)

Everything is working well, but I have no idea about how to Prepopulate the languages loaded from user's MySql database.

Example: mysql database result: 11,26,55

> Legend:
>   The user go to his profile's settings page, click on (Edit Languages).

`<input type="textbox" name="profile_languages" id="pro_token_languages">`

How to make the page prepopulate the three languages inside the textbox input?

11 => English (US)

26 => Portuguese (Brazil)

55 => Japanese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <input type="textbox" id="pro_token_languages" name="profile_languages" data-authors="<?php echo $language['lang']; ?>" />
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                  
   $("#pro_token_languages").tokenInput("YOUR_URL", {                                   
   theme: "facebook",
   preventDuplicates: true,                             
   prePopulate: $('#pro_token_languages').data('authors')                                            

  });   

});
```

But Don't Forget your SQL Query which included the returned JSON array including langiage names and id.
For Documentation Read Json Returned Format at   http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/